# Как убрать opacity c меню в мобильной версии?

Tags: javascript, css, css3

есть тестовая страница [ссылка](http://test-workflow.florans.md/)

я добавил с помощью JS что при открытии меню добавился opacity как убрать затемнение с меню, подкиньте идею

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вместо opacity использовать background: rgba(0,0,0,.4);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо удалить у `body - opacity`

Добавить

```
.body:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
   /* или */
   /* background-color: #293a43;
      opacity: .4; */
}
```